# Why is the first element of a class returned by Jarray.ToObject always null, even if the JSON itself has data assigned there?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json-deserialization

I'm attemtping to Deserialize the following data from a public API:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "₿",
    "rank": 1,
    "age": 4913,
    "color": "#fa9e32",
    "png32": "https://lcw.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/production/currencies/32/btc.png",
    "png64": "https://lcw.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/production/currencies/64/btc.png",
    "webp32": "https://lcw.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/production/currencies/32/btc.webp",
    "webp64":"https://lcw.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/production/currencies/64/btc.webp",
    "exchanges": 200,
    "markets": 4124,
    "pairs": 1361,
    "allTimeHighUSD": 68780.77475755227,
    "circulatingSupply": 19069418,
    "totalSupply": 19069418,
    "maxSupply": 21000000,
    "links": {
      "website": "https://bitcoin.org/",
      "whitepaper": "https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf",
      "twitter": null,
      "reddit": "https://reddit.com/r/bitcoin",
      "telegram": null,
      "discord": null,
      "medium": null,
      "instagram": null
    },
    "code": "BTC",
    "rate": 20270.674857910857,
    "volume": 19129604342,
    "cap": 386549972008
  }
]
```

So I created the following Template Classes and Deserializer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Arbitas
{


    public class Links
    {
        public string website { get; set; }
        public string whitepaper { get; set; }
        public string twitter { get; set; }
        public string reddit { get; set; }
        public string telegram { get; set; }
        public string discord { get; set; }
        public string medium { get; set; }
        public string instagram { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public int rank { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string png32 { get; set; }
        public string png64 { get; set; }
        public string webp32 { get; set; }
        public string webp64 { get; set; }
        public int exchanges { get; set; }
        public int markets { get; set; }
        public int pairs { get; set; }
        public double? allTimeHighUSD { get; set; }
        public double? circulatingSupply { get; set; }
        public double? totalSupply { get; set; }
        public int? maxSupply { get; set; }
        public Links links { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public double? rate { get; set; }
        public double? volume { get; set; }
        public double? cap { get; set; }
    }

    public class tokenDeserializer
    {
        public static List<Root> getTokenInformationFromAPI(string APIKey)
        {
            List<Root> trinf;
            var url = "https://api.livecoinwatch.com/coins/list";

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpRequest.Headers["x-api-key"] = APIKey;

            var data = "{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"sort\":\"rank\",\"order\":\"ascending\",\"offset\":0,\"limit\":1,\"meta\":false}";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JArray jresp = JArray.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

                trinf = jresp.ToObject<List<Root>>();
            }
            return trinf;

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to output the following, it does not output correctly:

```
public void SomeFunction(List<root> tokenOnbjects)
{
    foreach(root tk in tokenObjects)
        Console.WriteLine(tk.name + " - " + tk.code);
}
//Expected Output: Bitcoin - BTC
//Actual Output:  - BTC
```

Any ideas as to why the name field is not being deserialized? When checking the JSON Output directly in visual studio, it is showing that the parameter is there when the Json is fetched, but it is not stored when calling `Jarray.ToObject<List<Root>>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Having `"meta": false` in request payload your response does not contain full info - see [docs](https://livecoinwatch.github.io/lcw-api-docs/#coinslist).

Just change it to `true`:

```
// "meta": true
var data = "{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"sort\":\"rank\",\"order\":\"ascending\",\"offset\":0,\"limit\":1,\"meta\":true}";
```